# How to format integers slighty left in sql*plus?

Tags: sql, format, sqlplus

I have a question on how to format the values of a column to be slightly left justified=right.. Here is what i have:

[image]

The format Im looking for is justified right and the number should be in format of 'nn##' where # is representing 'space'. figure 2 shows what I'm looking for:

[image]

**UPADE_1**
The command `SELECT dname, deptno||'', loc FROM dept;` excecutes as:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
COLUMN dept_number Format A10 JUSTIFY CENTER;   
select lpad(to_char(dept_number),(10-length(dept_number)),' ') as dept_number 
from test;
```

Output
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. it messes everything up. See UPDATE_1

Comment: Check the updated answer. Now it is working. Thanks.